# TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to re-write this [code, which was written a while ago](http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/).

It has multiple chuncks, hence, I separated it into smaller pieces and re-write step by step. For instance, converting `.ix` to `iloc`, etc.

This chunk gives me an error:

```
#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

    if data.iloc[i][j] == 1:
        data_sims.iloc[i][j] = 0
    else:
        product_top_names = data_neighbours.iloc[product][1:10]
        product_top_sims = data_ibs.iloc[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]
        user_purchases = data_germany.iloc[user,product_top_names]

        data_sims.iloc[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)
```

Get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

I guess there is something here, which requires updating, but cannot find what exactly. I do not think it is about data. It is just about updating the code.

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: unrelated, but `data_sims.iloc[i][j] = ...` is index chaining assignment, and is unlikely to work. Also, it's not just the chunk that gives you error, you should specifically point out which line. Another thing I notice is your indentation might not be correct: `product` is defined inside `for j` loop, but used outside.

Comment: Also, as the error says, `iloc` is for integer indexing (much like numpy indexing). replace all `iloc[product]` with just column accessing `[product]` if slicing columns or `loc[product]` if slicing index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what that piece of code is supposed to do (though it seems like there may be a more efficient way of doing it). Also, it looks like you are referencing `j` outside the `j` loop.

However, the specific error you're getting is mostly likely related to:

```
product_top_names = data_neighbours.iloc[product][1:10]
```

`iloc` only works with integers, and I guess `product` is a string. If that's the case, something like

```
product_top_names = data_neighbours[product].iloc[1:10]
```

should get rid of the error (assuming `product` is the name of a column).

Answer (score 5):

Both answers were correct - by @nosuchthingasmagic and @Quang Hoang. Managed to debug everything.

I messed up with `.iloc` and `.loc`

The problem is here:

```
product_top_names = data_neighbours.loc[product][1:10]
product_top_sims = data_ibs.loc[product].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:10]
user_purchases = data_germany.loc[user,product_top_names]
```